# How to get a watch to work on my vrchat avatar

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have gotten into Unity to customise my VRchat avatar though I'm trying to add a watch that I got from the asset store on unity when I got to up load and load my game the watch isn't there but is on unity. Is there something I'm missing or am I going around this the wrong way as I only started using unity.

[image: VR-chat]
[image: Unity]

Comment: Could you also share a screenshot of your hierarchy? It may help us solve the problem faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the watch object is not set as the child of the Avatar object in the hierarchy. I'm imagining your hierarchy is looking like this.

```
.
├── Avatarname
│   ├── Armature
│   ├── ExtraObject
│   └── ExtraObject2
└── Watch
```

In this case, the VRC SDK will only upload `Avatarname` and everything below it, but will ignore any object on the same level (i.e. the watch object).

Place the watch object so it's set under `Avatarname`. You'll also want the watch to move along with the arm when in-game, so make sure to place the watch object under the bone (in the Armature) you want it to move a long with.

Answer (score 0):

As will-yama said, the watch are wrongly placed in the avatars hierarchy. Search for arm bone under the armature and then search for a wrist bone there. simply unpack the watch by right-clicking on them and then ,,Unpack prefab completly". After that, grab the watch and put them under the wrist bone in the hierarchy. This should fix your problem